# Calculate ranking based on table's score field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 models
1) business item
2) business service ranking
3) leaderboard

```
class BusinessServiceRanking < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :business_service
    belongs_to :leaderboard
    belongs_to :category
end


class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :leaderboards
    has_many :business_service_rankings
end

class BusinessItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :leaderboards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :business_service_rankings
end
```

leaderboards and business service rankings table has `rank` field with integer type and the business item has `score` field, now I want to calculate ranking based on `score` field. if score if 100 then rank should be 1, if the business item has the lowest score then its rank should be also lowest.

How can I do this?